# " Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\svgmember\admin\emp-profile.php on line 27"

Tags: php

I'm new for php. I got below message."Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\svgmember\admin\emp-profile.php on line 27"

this is my script

```
 <?php
    require_once('includes/start.php');
    include('includes/header.html');
     ?>



   <?php`$page_title = 'Edit Employee';
    if( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    }elseif( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    }else{
    echo '<p>Page Error</p>
     <p class="error">Page has been accessed in error!</p><p><br /><br />
    </p>';
    exit();}
    require_once('../dbcon.php');
     $query = "SELECT * FROM employee fname, bday, gender, nid, status, gsd, mpost, email, contact, address, activities,  WHERE mid=$id";
    $result = @mysql_query($query);

     if(mysql_num_rows($result) ==1){
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
     echo'<br>';
     echo '<h3><center>Employee Profile</center></h3>
    <table align="center" width="350">
     <tr>
     <td><b>Full Name:</b></td> <td>'.$row[0].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Birth Date:</b></td> <td>'.$row[1].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Gender:</b></td> <td>'.$row[2].'</td></tr>
      <tr>
     <td><b>National ID/Passport No:</b></td> <td>'.$row[3].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Status:</b></td> <td>'.$row[4].'</td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><b>GS Divition:</b></td> <td>'.$row[5].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Member Post:</b></td> <td>'.$row[6].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Email Address:</b></td> <td>'.$row[7].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Contact Number:</b></td> <td>'.$row[8].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Address:</b></td> <td>'.$row[9].'</td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Activities:</b></td> <td>'.$row[10].'</td></tr>';
    echo'</table> ';
         }else{
     echo '<p>Page Error</p>
     <p class="error">Page has been accessed in error!</p><p><br /><br /></p>';}

    mysql_close();
    ?>
    <br>

    <a href="../resume/<?php echo $fetch['resume']?>"><center>View Resume</center></a>
    <br>
    <?php
    require_once('../includes/footer.html');
    ?>
```

Please Help.....

Comment: try this $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE mid='$id'";

Comment: Please search for this before asking a question. This has been answered many times. See right column "Related".

Comment: please do not use deprecated mysql_* functions

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT fname, bday, gender, nid, status, gsd, mpost, email, contact, address,  
activities from employee WHERE mid='$id'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE mid='$id'";
```